# Keras k_pool2d backend function raises a type error

Tags: r, keras, incompatibletypeerror

I need to make some operations with the Keras backend functions for R and I'm getting the following type error with the `k_pool2d` function:

```
library(keras)

m <- array(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                    0, 1, 1, 0, 0), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE), dim=c(1, 5, 5, 1))

m <- k_constant(m)

k_pool2d(m, pool_size=c(2, 2), strides=c(1, 1), padding="valid", data_format="channels_last", pool_mode="max")
```

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
>
> Detailed traceback: 
>     File "/usr/local/share/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 4613, in pool2d
>       strides = (1,) + strides + (1,)

I understand that `strides=c(1, 1)` is a list instead a tuple, but this error does not raise with `pool_size=c(2, 2)`, for example. Trying the `k_conv2d` function does not raise this error either.

If I try to convert `c(1, 1)` to a tuple with `tuple(c(1, 1))` then a new error raises:

> Error in as.integer(strides): cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'integer'

This new error is the result of a conflict between `as.integer(tuple(c(1, 1)))` and the type of `m`, which is "environment".

Have any of you experienced this same issue?

Thank you in advance.